# Spring Data Neo4jTemplate.getOrCreateRelationship() method does not support property of array type?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm getting `RuntimeException` when calling `Neo4jTemplate.getOrCreateRelationship()` method and pass in properties which contains an `ArrayList`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error retrieving or creating relationship for key testKey and value 999 with index TestRelIndex
```

Here is my code:

```
Map<String, Object> relProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
tags.add("tag1");
tags.add("tag2");
relProperties.put("tags", tags);
Relationship rel = template.getOrCreateRelationship("TestRelIndex", "testKey", 999, userNode, itemNode, "shortlist", relProperties);
```

The exception message is not descriptive. After some debugging I managed to get the following error message from `org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingResAPI.getOrCreateRelationship()` method where the RuntimeException is thrown.

```
{"message":"Unknown property type on: [tag1, tag2], class java.util.ArrayList","exception":"IllegalArgumentException","fullname":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","stacktrace":["org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PropertyStore.encodeValue(PropertyStore.java:582)","org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.relAddProperty(WriteTransaction.java:1210)","org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.relAddProperty(PersistenceManager.java:176)","org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.relAddProperty(NodeManager.java:1156)","org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipImpl.addProperty(RelationshipImpl.java:69)","org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.setProperty(Primitive.java:436)","org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipImpl.setProperty(RelationshipImpl.java:29)","org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.setProperty(RelationshipProxy.java:129)","org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions$UniqueRelationshipFactory.initialize(DatabaseActions.java:1058)","org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions$UniqueRelationshipFactory.initialize(DatabaseActions.java:1033)","org.neo4j.graphdb.index.UniqueFactory.getOrCreateWithOutcome(UniqueFactory.java:241)","org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions.getOrCreateIndexedRelationship(DatabaseActions.java:1018)","org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.addToRelationshipIndex(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:871)","java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)","org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)"]}
```

I've tried to create the same relationship with `Neo4jTemplate.createRelationshipBetween()` and it's working fine. Does that mean `Neo4jTemplate.getOrCreateRelationship()` does not support property of array type yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly. You can store primitives, but not Objects like an `Array`. Try a custom serializer, or split your properties into an Array of Strings rather than a AraryList.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/8SZDaGTELnk gives some hints, too.